# Select sub-packages inside a main package for build

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a folder structure where there is a main package (mypkg) holding inside several sub-packages (subpkg1, subpkg2, ..., subpkgN):

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml
├── ...
└── mypkg/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpkg1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── module1.py
    └── subpkg2/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── module1.py
    ...
    └── subpkgN/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        └── moduleN.py
```

How to select only specific packages inside a main package using `pyproject.toml`? I tried setting

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = [
    "subpkg1",
    "subpkg2",
]
namespaces = false
```

But the problem is that `mypkg/__init__.py` is not added to the build. Is there a way to add this file?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `where = ["src"]` seems wrong, you might want to remove it. You do not seem to be using the so-called "*`src`*-layout".

You can choose to not use the `find` and instead list explicitly all packages (including sub-packages). Or you you can use `find` with its `include` and `exclude` options. If I am not mistaken, the list contents of `include` and `exclude` should be like in the following:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
exclude = [
    "mypkg.subpkg1*",
    "mypkg.subpkg2*",
]
```

***Reference***:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

Comment: removed the 'where = ["src"]' but still can't make the build to add 'mypkg/__init__.py'. Do you have a suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Probably the `include` and `exclude` were incorrect. I just added an example in my answer, but I am not 100% sure, I can not test right now. Check the documentation carefully.